# No internet with GPU

Tags: networking, ubuntu, gpu

This one has me puzzled. I have a system based around an MSI B75A-G43, with 6Gb of mismatched DDR3, and an Intel Celeron G530 CPU (x64). It runs Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 LTS, which runs fine except for a single issue :

Without a GPU (HD7870), I have internet connectivity. Plugging in the PCI-E connectors in the GPU, thus powering it up, then rebooting, results in a loss of connectivity.
The machine runs in headless mode, but typing blindly, I managed to execute `ifconfig >> log`, which returns only the local loop when the GPU is plugged in. When it isn't, I get the local loop AND my ethernet adapter.

Any thoughts on why the loss of an internet interface after a GPU is plugged in? System is up to date, AMD drivers are installed.

Last but not least, the system was previously running Debian 8 fine, with the Internet adapter recognized AS WELL AS the GPU, out of the box. So I don't get why Ubuntu would mess this up.

Thanks for reading ! Any advice appreciated

Comment: Does up-to-date include the latest BIOS/UEFI? This sounds like a hardware resource allocation issue between the PCIe slot and the onboard NIC. Poke around your BIOS for any relevant settings.

Comment: BIOS is up to date, and had been reset to factory settings previously (before I installed Debian 8, which had Internet + gpu, and Ubuntu Server, which causes the issue). The only relevant option I selected is "enable pci-e 3.0" which was disabled by default.

Comment: What output on the GPU are you using? I'm wondering if there is some EMI interfering with the NIC.

Comment: I have no output connected to the GPU, it was supposed to be a mass parallel computing device. When the GPU is disconnected, I use a VGA screen connected directly to the motherboard for debugging purposes.
I'm thinking it has to be software related, considering that Debian 8 worked OOTB

Comment: I would start by checking if your NIC is showing up in `lspci -v` output, and if any error messages appear in `dmesg`. And I certainly wouldn't debug this by typing blindly on a headless machine. You can configure Ubuntu to provide a login prompt on a [serial console](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SerialConsoleHowto), which will remain accessible even if there's no network.

Comment: Are you plugging in (or powering on) the GPU while the machine is running? That is a bloody good way of damaging the motherboard and/or the GPU.

Comment: No, I know that PCI-E, even if it's supposed to be, is not hot pluggable. Every switch from GPU to no GPU is done when the machine is powered off, and the power supply switched off.